# About : CreateContainerError

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-pod

i installed K8S cluster in my laptop, it was running fine in the beginning but when i restarted my laptop then some services were not running.

```
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-9nm6m             0/1     Error                  594        12d
kube-system   coredns-5c98db65d4-qwkk9             0/1     CreateContainerError


kube-system   kube-scheduler-kubemaster            0/1     CreateContainerError
```

I searched online for solution but could not get appropriate answer ,
please help me resolve this issue

Comment: How did you install it? You can easily get a local cluster running by installing docker and enabling the kubernetes feature.

Comment: i installed "apt-get install -y docker.io kubeadm kubectl kubelet" and followed necessary steps. installation is successful but when i restarted my system the above pods are throwing errors

Comment: there is more to setting up a cluster than installing the cli tools. If you want to run locally you should use either docker)https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/kubernetes/) or minikube(https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/). I use the docker version, it works well out of the box (you just need to increase memory allocation in docker settings).

Comment: hi i need to work on the vm's on my laptop , so i need to resolve this issue .

Comment: Did you try minikube or docker?

Comment: No, i did not tried those, i want to implement my project in multinode cluster so i tried in the vm's and i deployed nginx but later when i restarted my system these errors poped up.

Answer (score 2):

I encourage you to look for [official kubernetes documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/). Remember that your kubemaster should have at least fallowing resources: 2CPUs or more, 2GB or more of RAM.

1. Firstly install [docker](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/) and [kubeadm](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/) (as a root user) on each machine.
2. Initialize kubeadm (on master):

```
kubeadm init <args>
```

For example for Calico to work correctly, you need to pass `--pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16` to kubeadm init:

```
kubeadm init --pod-network-cidr=192.168.0.0/16
```

3. Install a [pod network](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#pod-network) add-on (depends on what you would like to use). You can install a pod network add-on with the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f <add-on.yaml>
```

e.g. for Calico:

```
kubectl apply -f https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.8/manifests/calico.yaml
```

4. To start using your cluster, you need to run on master the following as a regular user:

```
mkdir -p $HOME/.kube
sudo cp -i /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf $HOME/.kube/config
sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

5. You can now join any number of machines by running the following on each node as root:

```
kubeadm join <master-ip>:<master-port> --token <token> --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:<hash>
```

By default, **tokens expire after 24 hours**. If you are joining a node to the cluster after the current token has expired, you can create a new token by running the following command on the control-plane node:

```
kubeadm token create
```

Please, let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Hi, i reinstalled my vm's again ,now all the services are running fine , but i want to know the cause of the error.thanks

Comment: Please show me logs from pods where errors occured.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the status of docker and kubelet services.? if not, please run below commands and verify that services are up and running.

```
  systemctl status docker kubelet
```

Comment: yes i checked the status of docker and kubelet they are actively running , i also want to know why   CreateContainerError occurred and how to resolve it , thanks

Comment: Ok. Can you check this settings .?                                                                       
      1.  cat /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables  [ the output should be "1"   ]
      2.  sestatus   [ Make sure that it is still disabled ]

Comment: hi, for this cat /proc/sys/net/bridge/bridge-nf-call-iptables ---- the status is 1,but sestatus is not installed

Comment: Ok.  We have to check the logs for this pods. Can you please run kubectl -n kube-system logs <pod's name>  for all failed pods and provide the logs over here.

Comment: ya i tried for the logs , but kubectl logs <podname> is not showing the logs and throwing error i.e -- no such pod exists